# Trouble with finding regex expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I  a newbie to regx. I am unable to get things right with his. Can some one help me with this. I have a web page source code, where in i need to locate this pattern:

```
http://cdn1b.mobile.website.com/videos/201102/18/174092/240P_245K_174092.mp4?rs=125&amp;ri=600&amp;s=1394217550&amp;e=1394228350&amp;h=b99d1d9d38da8ba3ab99601de0cf794e
```

I need to get only one instance of this even if there are more. But i am getting  selection from first http in the page to the last `mp4?rs=125&amp;ri=600&amp;s=1394217550&amp;e=1394228350&amp;h=b99d1d9d38da8ba3ab99601de0cf794e`

in the page. I am using php.

Edited: This is what i was trying. (sorry if its stupid)

```
(http(s?):).*\.(mp4|flv|mkv|avi)(\?rs=[A-Za-z0-9=]+).*.(ri=[A-Za-z0-9=]+).*.(s=[A-Za-z0-9=]+).*.(e=[A-Za-z0-9=]+).*.(h=[A-Za-z0-9=]+)
```

Edited:  Here is a pastebin of what i am getting with my expression

http://pastebin.com/trmNzMti

Comment: Can you show your current regex/code?

Comment: Please provide your current regexp in php and what exactly you want as output

Comment: @tenub I think he's after URIs of that form, not a specific string.

Comment: Pattern example:

http://cdn1b.mobile.website.com/videos/201102/18/174092/240P_245K_174092.mp4?rs=125&amp;ri=600&amp;s=1394217550&amp;e=1394228350&amp;h=b99d1d9d38da8ba3ab99601de0cf794e

cdn1b.mobile.website.com/videos/201102/18/174092/240P_245K_174092
This part may change in future so the pattern will be based on :

Starts with http or https ends with .mp4?rs=125&amp;ri=600&amp;s=1394217550&amp;e=1394228350&amp;h=b99d1d9d38da8ba3ab99601de0cf794e

Comment: PHP has special parameters on its regex functions to limit the match count. Otherwise use callback and break the function after 1 loopcycle.

Comment: Try making your `*` and `+` quantifiers non-greedy by putting `?` after them.

Comment: I would just go with something simple like this: `http.+?\/videos\/.+?\.(?:mp4|flv|mkv|avi)[^ ]*` if you're trying to extract video links.

Comment: Dont focus content/pattern after http:// till .mp4 .That is changeable. 'videos' may not be there tomorrow.

Check the paste bin output of what i got with my incorrect expression. At the end you will see the actual pattern lies.

Comment: Hope the question isnt confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it :

```
preg_match_all("/(http(s?):)([^\s]+)\.(mp4|flv|mkv|avi)(\?rs=[A-Za-z0-9=]+)([^\s]+)(ri=[A-Za-z0-9=]+)([^\s]+)(s=[A-Za-z0-9=]+)([^\s]+)(e=[A-Za-z0-9=]+)([^\s]+)(h=[A-Za-z0-9=]+)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// each occurrence
foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";
}

// first occurrence
echo $matches[0][0]
```

Changed `*` to `([^\s]+)` matches anything except spaces, you can add other characters you wish to exclude between desired matches.

Comment: It didnt work it gives the same output as mine. Selects from first occurrence of http till last occurrence of .mp4?....

Please see the pastebin link

Comment: Ok for some reason that just worked!! thank you very much. It was a mountain for me by myself. Unfortunately i am a newbie here and cant voteup

Comment: No problem, pleased it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find a url in string by regExp check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22202821/preg-match-all-regex-to-find-full-urls-in-string/22203057#22203057) which has a full patterns for different requests

If you have the url string and want to find a parameter in the query string use `parse_url()` command [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Example:

```
$query = parse_url('http://cdn1b.mobile.website.com/videos/201102/18/174092/240P_245K_174092.mp4?rs=125&amp;ri=600&amp;s=1394217550&amp;e=1394228350&amp;h=b99d1d9d38da8ba3ab99601de0cf794e');
//to get whatever after http or https and before the filename in url you can use this:
$specifict_section = $query['host'].str_replace(basename($query['path'], '', $query['path']));

$query_parts = explode('&amp;', $query['query']);
$params = array(); 
foreach ($query_parts as $param) { 
    $item = explode('=', $param); 
    $params[$item[0]] = $item[1]; 
} 

// Do your stuffs with $params
print_r( $params );
```

Comment: javad i dont want the params. SEE for example if this is the url:

http://cdn1b.mobile.website.com/videos/201102/18/174092/240P_245K_174092.mp4?rs=125&amp;ri=600&amp;s=1394217550&amp;e=1394228350&amp;h=b99d1d9d38da8ba3ab99601de0cf794e

I want to find the url in the page code. the part after http, namely:
cdn1b.mobile.website.com/videos/201102/18/174092/

May be anything. it may even change in future. the trailer part is what identifies the url in the page.

Comment: Great, still you can use `parse_url()` check my added section to the top solution, I am sure it will help you